# How to split string in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I  am trying to split `data_set_path` first by `,` than In side loop I should be able to split string by `->`.Please help me.

```
set "data_set_path=v1->E:\test1,v2->E:\test2,v3->E:\test3,v4->E:\test4"
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal 
set "data_set_path=v1->E:\test1,v2->E:\test2,v3->E:\test3,v4->E:\test4"
REM first split by commas
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%i in ("%data_set_path%") do set "pc1=%%i"& set "pc2=%%j"& set "pc3=%%k"&set "pc4=%%l"
<nul set/p"=1st split: %pc1% %pc2% %pc2% %pc4%"&echo( 
REM second split by "->"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=->" %%i in ("%data_set_path%") do set "pp1=%%i"& set "pp2=%%j"& set "pp3=%%k"&set "pp4=%%l"
echo 2nd split: %pp1% %pp2% %pp2% %pp4%
REM third split by "->"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=->" %%a in ("%pc1%") do set "pc11=%%a"&set "pc12=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=->" %%a in ("%pc2%") do set "pc21=%%a"&set "pc22=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=->" %%a in ("%pc3%") do set "pc31=%%a"&set "pc32=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=->" %%a in ("%pc4%") do set "pc41=%%a"&set "pc42=%%b"
echo 3nd split: %pc11% %pc12% %pc21% %pc22% %pc31% %pc32% %pc41% %pc42%
```

.. output is:

```
1st split: v1->E:\test1 v2->E:\test2 v2->E:\test2 v4->E:\test4
2nd split: v1 E:\test1,v2 E:\test1,v2 E:\test3,v4
3nd split: v1 E:\test1 v2 E:\test2 v3 E:\test3 v4 E:\test4
```

Comment: Endoro I need to split string first by comma .Than on each string inside loop(say my first element is v1->E:\test1) I have to again split that means I should have v1 and E:\test1 as a separate value.

Comment: The first split is by comma and the 3th is the split of the first splitted now by "->". So forget the 2nd split I made because I was not sure what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use variable expansion search and replace to convert delimiter into line feed. FOR /F iterates  at line feeds.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define LF to contain a line feed (0x0A)
set LF=^


:: Above 2 empty lines are critical - DO NOT REMOVE

set "data_set_path=v1->E:\test1,v2->E:\test2,v3->E:\test3,v4->E:\test4"
for %%L in ("!LF!") do (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!data_set_path:,=%%~L!") do (
    set "split1=%%A"
    set "split2a="
    set "split2b="
    for /f "delims=" %%B in ("!split1:->=%%~L!") do (
      if not defined split2a (set "split2a=%%B") else set "split2b=%%B"
    )
    echo name=!split2a!  value=!split2b!
  )
)
```

--OUTPUT--

```
name=v1  value=E:\test1
name=v2  value=E:\test2
name=v3  value=E:\test3
name=v4  value=E:\test4
```

The code above fails if name or value begins with `;` due to FOR /F EOL feature.

The code also fails if `!` appears anywhere within content due to delayed expansion being active when FOR variable is expanded.

Both problems can be solved if need be.